# Update firestore array from another collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update the id color field of a firestore collection from another one, both within the firestore and I am having difficulties.

see my collections ...

1 - colors

[image]

2 - imports

[image]

this was my last attempt, see if you can get an idea ...

```
 let dataImportRef = firestore.db
      .collection(process.env.COLLECTION_IMPORT)
      .where("id", "==", importId); //import utility
    let dataColorsRef = firestore.db.collection("colors"); 

    //import collection
    dataImportRef
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          let arrayImport = doc.data().documentsDetail;

          for (var i = 0; i < arrayImport.length; i++) {
            //console.log(arrayImport[i].cor);
            let tmpColor = arrayImport[i].cor;

            dataColorsRef
              .where("name", "==", tmpColor)
              .get()
              .then((snap) => {
                if (!snap.empty) {
                  snap.forEach((res) => {
                    //console.log(tmpColor, "=>", res.data().id);
                    const thing = arrayImport[0];
                    thing.ref.update({ id_color: res.data().id });
                  });
                }
              });
          }
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents", err);
      });
```

error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

any tips on how to update the id_cor field from the colors collection using as key name (colors collection) and color (imports collection)?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code that's not working the way you expect.  I can't tell at all what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @DougStevenson 
I posted my last attempt to try to give an idea of ​​my goal. See if you can give me a tip? Thank you

Comment: The error is tellng you that `thing.ref` is undefined.  Why do you think that is?

Comment: @DougStevenson 
In this line I am in two for, the main import collection and then the color collection.
I think that at this point I should update the main collection (imports) with the id_cor from the color collection, but it has not worked ... I am not sure if this is the way to do it.

Comment: You cannot update fields like that in firestore.
you have to remove the element and then add the new element.
Check this link: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Comment: @Edwin really the best way was to remove and recreate the node. thank you.

Comment: Glad that helped.